# Determine limit of sequance if it exists

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the limit of sequence  $a_n=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+ ...+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\ln(\sqrt{n})$ if it exists else explain why it doesn't exist.

**My try**:
I tried to use thm that if $a_n$ is bounded and  monotonic then it is convergent.
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\ln(\sqrt{n+1})+\ln(\sqrt{n})=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{n}{n+1})=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-\frac{1}{n+1})>\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}>0$$
But don't know to bound it above.

Comment: No we didn't learn that yet.

Comment: Are you aware that $\log(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}$? This is pretty much effective in establishing the behaviour of $\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a elementary fashion we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)&=&\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{n+x}=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{n+\frac{1}{2}+x}\\&=&\int_{0}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}+x}+\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}-x}\right)\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{z^2}{4n+2}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
so for any $n\geq 1$
$$ \log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^2}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\frac{z^2}{4}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\,dz$$
is bounded by $\frac{1}{12}\cdot\frac{1}{n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(n+1)}$ and it is decreasing towards zero as $n\to +\infty$.
This essentially is a naive implementation of the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality).
Since $\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$ are pretty close (with the former being a telescopic term) and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(n+1)}$ is finite (equal to $\frac{3-4\log 2}{6}$) your sequence is convergent.

The Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ is exactly defined as $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(H_n-\log n\right)$. From
$$ H_n = \log(n) + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
we have
$$ H_{2n}-\frac{1}{2}H_n-\frac{1}{2}\log(n) = \underbrace{\color{red}{\frac{\gamma}{2}+\log 2}}_{\approx 0.981755}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Long story short, your limit is just a bit less than one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use the definition of the Euler constant,

$$a_n=H_{2n}-\frac12H_n-\log2n+\frac12\log n+\log2.$$

The first difference cancels out all even harmonic terms and the remaining terms account for $\log\sqrt n$.

Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\gamma-\frac12\gamma+\log2.$$